# Make string comparison case insensitive

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched for this but didn't find it explained for VBA.

How do I make a string comparison, such as this, case insensitive:

```
If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
    For Each word In wordsArr
        For Each element In arr
            If word = element Then counter = counter + 1
        Next
    Next
Else
    ' cell to search is empty
    counter = 0
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:
`LCase(word) = LCase(element)`
or UCase(), if all words in wordsArr are lowercase (uppercase) you can use LCase(UCase) only on the left side of comparison.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
StrComp(word, element, vbTextCompare) = 0
```

as well.